# Selenium proxy server argument - unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Hope you're well.

I am facing a little problem when trying to set-up my chrome webdriver. I am trying to change the parameters of the webdriver to rotate the User Agent & the IP (I use it for scraping purpose & don't want to get spot with the same IP & UA).

When I pass the UA argument, everything works well. But when I add the IP argument, it systematically fails for some reasons that I can't identify. I always receive the following error

````
WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)```
````

The behavior is always the same, the driver opens the web page as requested, then the page loads for a while until indicating the site is not accessible.

Below is the code used. Do you have any idea where it could come from? (I have not able to find similar posts on this unfortunately)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



opts = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 CK={} (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
PROXY = '176.9.119.170:8080'

opts.add_argument("user-agent="+user_agent)
opts.add_argument("--proxy-server=%s" % PROXY)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='XXXXXXXX', options=opts)
        

driver.get('https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip')
user_agent_check = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
print(user_agent_check)
```

Traceback below

```
# Licensed to the Software Freedom Conservancy (SFC) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The SFC licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

from selenium.common.exceptions import (ElementClickInterceptedException,
                                        ElementNotInteractableException,
                                        ElementNotSelectableException,
                                        ElementNotVisibleException,
                                        ErrorInResponseException,
                                        InsecureCertificateException,
                                        InvalidCoordinatesException,
                                        InvalidElementStateException,
                                        InvalidSessionIdException,
                                        InvalidSelectorException,
                                        ImeNotAvailableException,
                                        ImeActivationFailedException,
                                        InvalidArgumentException,
                                        InvalidCookieDomainException,
                                        JavascriptException,
                                        MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException,
                                        NoSuchCookieException,
                                        NoSuchElementException,
                                        NoSuchFrameException,
                                        NoSuchWindowException,
                                        NoAlertPresentException,
                                        ScreenshotException,
                                        SessionNotCreatedException,
                                        StaleElementReferenceException,
                                        TimeoutException,
                                        UnableToSetCookieException,
                                        UnexpectedAlertPresentException,
                                        UnknownMethodException,
                                        WebDriverException)

try:
    basestring
except NameError:  # Python 3.x
    basestring = str


class ErrorCode(object):
    """
    Error codes defined in the WebDriver wire protocol.
    """
    # Keep in sync with org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes and errorcodes.h
    SUCCESS = 0
    NO_SUCH_ELEMENT = [7, 'no such element']
    NO_SUCH_FRAME = [8, 'no such frame']
    UNKNOWN_COMMAND = [9, 'unknown command']
    STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE = [10, 'stale element reference']
    ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE = [11, 'element not visible']
    INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE = [12, 'invalid element state']
    UNKNOWN_ERROR = [13, 'unknown error']
    ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE = [15, 'element not selectable']
    JAVASCRIPT_ERROR = [17, 'javascript error']
    XPATH_LOOKUP_ERROR = [19, 'invalid selector']
    TIMEOUT = [21, 'timeout']
    NO_SUCH_WINDOW = [23, 'no such window']
    INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN = [24, 'invalid cookie domain']
    UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE = [25, 'unable to set cookie']
    UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN = [26, 'unexpected alert open']
    NO_ALERT_OPEN = [27, 'no such alert']
    SCRIPT_TIMEOUT = [28, 'script timeout']
    INVALID_ELEMENT_COORDINATES = [29, 'invalid element coordinates']
    IME_NOT_AVAILABLE = [30, 'ime not available']
    IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED = [31, 'ime engine activation failed']
    INVALID_SELECTOR = [32, 'invalid selector']
    SESSION_NOT_CREATED = [33, 'session not created']
    MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS = [34, 'move target out of bounds']
    INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR = [51, 'invalid selector']
    INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER = [52, 'invalid selector']

    ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE = [60, 'element not interactable']
    INSECURE_CERTIFICATE = ['insecure certificate']
    INVALID_ARGUMENT = [61, 'invalid argument']
    INVALID_COORDINATES = ['invalid coordinates']
    INVALID_SESSION_ID = ['invalid session id']
    NO_SUCH_COOKIE = [62, 'no such cookie']
    UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN = [63, 'unable to capture screen']
    ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED = [64, 'element click intercepted']
    UNKNOWN_METHOD = ['unknown method exception']

    METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = [405, 'unsupported operation']


class ErrorHandler(object):
    """
    Handles errors returned by the WebDriver server.
    """
    def check_response(self, response):
        """
        Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

        :Args:
         - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
           object.

        :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
        """
        status = response.get('status', None)
        if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
            return
        value = None
        message = response.get("message", "")
        screen = response.get("screen", "")
        stacktrace = None
        if isinstance(status, int):
            value_json = response.get('value', None)
            if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
                import json
                try:
                    value = json.loads(value_json)
                    if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                        value = value['value']
                    status = value.get('error', None)
                    if status is None:
                        status = value["status"]
                        message = value["value"]
                        if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                            value = message
                            message = message.get('message')
                    else:
                        message = value.get('message', None)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
        if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
            exception_class = NoSuchElementException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
            exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
            exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
        elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
            exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
            exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
                or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
            exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
            exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
            exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
            exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
            exception_class = TimeoutException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
            exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
        elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
            exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
            exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
        elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
            exception_class = JavascriptException
        elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
            exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
            exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
        elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
            exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
            exception_class = ScreenshotException
        elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
            exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
            exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
            exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
        elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
            exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
        elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
            exception_class = UnknownMethodException
        else:
            exception_class = WebDriverException
        if value == '' or value is None:
            value = response['value']
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
                raise exception_class(response, value)
            raise exception_class(value)
        if message == "" and 'message' in value:
            message = value['message']

        screen = None
        if 'screen' in value:
            screen = value['screen']

        stacktrace = None
        if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
            stacktrace = []
            try:
                for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                    line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                    file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                    if line:
                        file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                    meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                    if 'className' in frame:
                        meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                    msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                    msg = msg % (meth, file)
                    stacktrace.append(msg)
            except TypeError:
                pass
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if 'data' in value:
                alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
            elif 'alert' in value:
                alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

    def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
        return obj[key] if key in obj else default
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are chromedriver and chrome versions compatible?

Comment: I guess yes, otherwise I would have had an issue before the IP thing, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is the correct way to add proxy in chrome ,

JAVA:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
String proxyadd = "176.9.119.170:8080";
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyadd);
proxy.setSslProxy(proxyadd);
chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

PYTHON:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY="176.9.119.170:8080"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True

driver =webdriver.Chrome(r".\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

It seems that chrome is not able to connect to proxy may be it is using system proxy. Try above mentioned approach to set proxy

**Full code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROXY="localhost:8888"

opts = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 CK={} (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True


opts.add_argument("user-agent="+user_agent)

print(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

driver =webdriver.Chrome(r".\chromedriver.exe",options=opts)


driver.get("https://wrong.host.badssl.com/")

driver.get('https://www.expressvpn.com/what-is-my-ip')
user_agent_check = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
print(user_agent_check)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Looks like this one is in Java, which I am not really an expert of. But what are we trying to do here exactly? Why should we declare the localhost to unlock the problem?

Comment: @RaphaëlAmbit Hi added for python alsow

Comment: @RaphaëlAmbit taht was an example of how to set proxy

Comment: Tunnel is usually related ssl ,

Comment: Got it now, thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately I tried this one too (just tried again with your code though) and it leads to the same result

Comment: https://thegeekpage.com/solved-fix-err_tunnel_connection_failed-error-in-chrome/

Comment: is your proxy server works ? does it connect to internet

Comment: webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True add this also and see

Comment: Yes I haven't spot any problem with the proxy server (I hope I have not missed anything though). But to your point on the connection, I get the same outcome if I manually specify my local machine (which is well connected without any doubt)

I've just tried the updated code but still leading to the same result :/ 

I have added the entire traceback in my initial post, not sure if it can help.

Comment: @RaphaëlAmbit i added the full code that works for me , try adding a sleep and try opening any other website in the chrome opened using selenium then you can verify whther your proxy is able to connect tto internet. Replace localhost:8888 to 176.9.119.170:8080 for your case as thats your proxxy

Comment: Thank you for the full code.

I've just tried it & noticed the following behavior. The error no longer happens if my regular chrome is closed (but if for some reason I keep my chrome running while the selenium is active, the issue remains. Not sure how those can conflict with each other).

The other strange behavior I have noticed is that the IP returned is not stable. Sometimes I actually get the proxy IP passed in the code, sometimes it returns my real IP. Not sure if this comes from the way we pass it (i.e. easy to pierce for IP checking sites or there if another reason)

Comment: @RaphaëlAmbit is your proxy server behind the same nat router ?

Comment: you proxy ip looks like a local IP so it means even proxy server connects to internet using the NAT which has same publiuc IP for both your local system and proxy

Comment: @RaphaëlAmbit the issue of conflict may be because by default chrome uses system proxy , but through selenium we are explicitly changing this behavior so that might be causing the issue