# Error with Proxy Selenium Webdriver Python : ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I have made a bot in python with selenium but i have an error that i can't pass.

My script run X number of time , each time with a new proxy, the problem is sometimes the proxy don't work and the script crash

I have message "can't reach this site" or "err_connection_failed", i have try with webdriverwait , do a loop to try if it can pass but still blocked, when the driver.get.url can't connect to the website , the script crash.

[Screen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJTLq.jpg)

Thanks for your help

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

temp = True
while temp:
    try:
        # Add your proxxy change code here
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
        temp = False
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        driver.quit()
```

you can add something like this to catch the exception and try again until it passes

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts']=True
```

like suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156932/selenium-proxy-server-argument-unknown-error-neterr-tunnel-connection-faile). It worked for me.